# String Values are repeating When using sample function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For every employee, there will be a random child employee, in this case when I try to run this program the same child employee is repeating again and again for other Employees. What do i need to do for that? it should not repeat

```py
import random as rm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nm

from pandas import Series, DataFrame

CHCbot_Emp = DataFrame({'Employee_Name':['Deepak','Varadharajan','Akash','Jeffrin','Ashwini','Sathish','Vikram','Narasiman','satyavathi'],
                       'Employee_Code':['IS4001','IS4002','IS4003','IS4004','IS4005','IS4006','IS4007','IS4008','IS4009']})
CHCbot_Emp

for rows in CHCbot_Emp.itertuples(index=False):
    print(rows.Employee_Name+" "+rows.Employee_Code)
    print('Hey '+rows.Employee_Name+'!!! Pick your Child')
    random_Variable = CHCbot_Emp.sample(n=1)
    print(random_Variable.Employee_Code+" "+random_Variable.Employee_Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dataframe.sample()` is only a sampling technique where a sample of n=3 are all unique. In this case, you are generating a sample of n=1 everytime, and each generation are independent of each other so you will not get unique items.

One approach to generate non-repeating random numbers is to create a list using `range(n)`, then shuffle the list using `random.shuffle()`. Now you have the random numbers list, you can take out each element from this list using `list.pop()`

Example:

```
import numpy as np

from pandas import Series,DataFrame

CHCbot_Emp = DataFrame({'Employee_Name':['Deepak','Varadharajan','Akash','Jeffrin','Ashwini','Sathish','Vikram','Narasiman','satyavathi'],
                       'Employee_Code':['IS4001','IS4002','IS4003','IS4004','IS4005','IS4006','IS4007','IS4008','IS4009']})
CHCbot_Emp

l = list(range(len(CHCbot_Emp)))
np.random.shuffle(l)

for rows in CHCbot_Emp.itertuples(index=False):
    print(rows.Employee_Name+" "+rows.Employee_Code)
    print('Hey '+rows.Employee_Name+'!!! Pick your Child')
    random_Variable = CHCbot_Emp.iloc[l.pop()]
    print(random_Variable.Employee_Code+" "+random_Variable.Employee_Name)
```

Here I used `dataframe.iloc[l.pop()]` to to get your random dataframe row.

Another option is to use [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) instead of `.shuffle()`

```
l = random.sample(list(range(len(CHCbot_Emp))),len(CHCbot_Emp))
```